# On google analytics, when I see visits / keywords are all these vists are of unique visitors?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

On google analytics, when I see visits / keywords are all these vists are of unique visitors or are they other visits of 1 visitor who came to the site using that keyword in the first place ?

Answer (score 1):

The visits are session visits. A session expires after 30 minutes of inactivity, unless otherwise configured by you.

See http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=57164 for more info.

Comment: So does that mean that 10 people came from the keyword "hello world is cool" or does that mean that 10 visits came from 1 visitor who first entered from this keyword?

Comment: It could be both. There were 10 unique sessions, but you don't know how many users are behind them.

Comment: Minor addition: A Google Analytics session expires if one of two things happens: 30 minutes of inactivity or closing the entire browser. So even if it's been less then 30 minutes since your last pageview, if you (completely, not just the tab) closed your browser in the meantime, your are a new session and counted as a new visit.